# how to send passwords as a query parameter in amazon api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to pass credentials through the api gateway to the connected lambda function as
https://2ty6aekde.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test/endpoint?Email=abc@example.com&password=123

here the password being passed is 123. how can the password be encrypted such that "123" is not visible/encrypted in the url and still reaches the lambda function?

Comment: As jogold mentioned, passing a **password in a query string is an incredibly bad practice for all sorts of reasons**. Passwords should always be posted.

Comment: Sure, but how would you post it to an AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to API Gateway or AWS in any way.

**Passing passwords in query strings is a really bad practice** because URLs are usually logged on servers. Passwords should always be POSTed.

If you don't want to POST passwords in clear, you might have a look at the [Secure Remote Password protocol](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol).